# Msbuild not finding reference to a dll of another project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have hit this problem today but have failed to solve it.

My solution has a few projects and I have modified two of them to take into consideration a change. In order to complete the change, I referenced the dll of one project in other by using add reference. Everything compiles perfectly in VS2010, but as soon as I point it to build server it fails saying it can't find the reference of the other project. The particular class I need to use is marked as copy to output folder always.

So, can anyone help me?

Comment: Assuming all the projects are in the same solution you should be adding a project reference and not a dll reference.  If this is not the case include how you are telling msbuild to build things, and if the project that has the dll you want is being built.

Comment: No, I think you have misunderstood me, referencing I  am using in the other project is the compiled project dll not a class. So, I am using the project reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was due to the build order, which surprised me did not show up in the IDE. However I have read that the way vs builds is different to msbuild.